# if cell a has a value and cell b matches a specific value than present cell a

Tags: excel

I'm not quite sure how to explain this, but essentially I am trying to have an automatically generated list of rooms be created on a excel sheet.  So the raw data looks like this:

```
A1: Room 1       B1: A  C1:(Numerical data)
A2: (no value)   B2: A  C2:(Numerical data)
A3: Room 2       B3: B  C3:(Numerical data) 
A4:  (no value)  B4: B  C4:(Numerical data)
```

Basically I'm looking for a formula that is something like `If A1:A1000 has data And B1:B1000 = A (on the same row) than put the matching "A" column data in this cell`

The final sheet should look like:

```
A1: Room 1 B1: (Sum of numerical data for all type "A")
A2: Room 2 B2: (Sum of numerical data for all type "B")
```

With this formula being in the `A column`

Comment: This seems very pivot-table-ish.

Comment: For the purpose of writing the formula completely, what is the name of your raw data sheet?

Comment: Have you tried using the Subtotal feature (found in the Outline section of the Data tab)? It seems like this would do what you're describing if instead of leaving blanks, you filled the data column with the correct Room number (which would give your table a better, more flexible data structure).

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, Here is the (simplified to match example) formula I used to come close

=IF(LOOKUP(a,b1:b1000)=a,LOOKUP(a,b1:b1000,A1:A1000),0)

It seems to work but only if the table looks like this:

A1: Room 1       B1: A  C1:(Numerical data)
A2: Room 1       B2: A  C2:(Numerical data)
A3: Room 2       B3: B  C3:(Numerical data)
A4: Room 2       B4: B  C4:(Numerical data)

The only catch is I didn't want to have to have Room 1, etc. listed over and over but if I leave cell A2 blank in this example it returns an error.

Oh, and just in case I screwed something up in the example formula above, here is the exact formula from my spreadsheet. =IF(LOOKUP(M11,G$11:G$1000)=M11,LOOKUP(M11,$G$11:$G$1000,$A$11:$A$1000),0)

(M11 is a cell with the letter A in it, column G is equivalent to column B in the example spreadsheet and Column A is column A.)